# How to sent query results (SQL Server 2016) as hyperlink (Microsoft Outlook) via middleware (C#)

Tags: c#, outlook, sql-server-2016

I need to send an email from bought application. That application has an extention (C#, dll) which allows to sent an email using smtm. I need to sent a hyperlink created via applications as a result of SQL-Server query. Hyperlink is used to connect to that application and open a specific document inside. The problem is an unusual format:

```
appName:param1=XXX&param2=YYY
```

Where appName is a link to .exe in registry.
That format is not recognized as hyperlink inside Microsoft Outlook, so users need to copy that string and create an shortcut on their machines instead simply clicking on that. (https://stackoverflow.com/ could be sent via extension and Outlook recognizes that as hyperlink)

I cannot modify that dll with extension, moreover I cannot write my own extension (guarantee agreement).

I`ve tried:

1. using html ( )
2. creation of message in outlook, next using source as a template for query
3. use  "for xml path"
   Each of results above outlook recognized as a plain text.

I`ll be gateful for any hints.
Maybe there is a list of keywords for hyperlink in Outlook?

Summary: I can only edit email body via sql server query or change something in Microsoft Outlook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem has been solved by prefix url:

```
url:appName:param1=XXX&param2=YYY
```